# Window function needs group by, but why?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an ecommerce and want to measure retention after 60 days of the first sale.
A retained user has done at least one purchase between the next 60 days.

I have a sales table with the following information:

```
Sale ID | Customer ID | Date
1       |  405        | 2021-03-05
2       |  408        | 2021-03-06
3       |  231        | 2021-03-07
```

I'm having issues with the part that calculates the retention.

I try to use this query:

```
SELECT
         "Customer ID",
         COUNT("Sale ID") OVER(
            PARTITION BY "Customer ID"
            ORDER BY "Date" ASC
            RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND INTERVAL '60 days' FOLLOWING
            ) AS "60 days Sales"
            
         FROM "Sales"
      GROUP BY "Customer ID"
```

After trying this, I get this error:
`ERROR: Column "Date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in aggregate`

I expect that query to get the number of sales done between those 60 days for any given customer. That way, I can use that later and filter customers as retained or churned.

What am I doing wrong? I'm not sure why "Date" should be grouped: I expect the result to be grouped by Customer ID.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add sample data to the question.

Comment: Once you've done the grouping then you can only refer to aggregates of `date`. It's probably confusing but this is part of the difference between analytic functions and aggregate functions.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that window functions are evaluated *after* `GROUP BY`, so PostgreSQL doesn't know which of the `"Date"` in one group you mean.

You should probably use a filtered aggregate rather than a window function. I am not sure what exactly you intend to query, but maybe it is something similar to the following:

```
SELECT "Customer ID",
       COUNT("Sale ID")
          FILTER (WHERE "Date" BETWEEN current_timestamp
                               AND current_timestamp + INTERVAL '60 days')
          AS "60 days Sales"
FROM "Sales"
GROUP BY "Customer ID";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select "Customer ID",
    case when max("60 days Sales") > 1 then 'Retained' else 'Churned' end as Status
from (
    SELECT
        "Customer ID",
        COUNT("Sale ID") OVER(
            PARTITION BY "Customer ID"
            ORDER BY "Date" ASC
            RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND INTERVAL '60 days' FOLLOWING
        ) AS "60 days Sales"            
    FROM "Sales"
) t
group by "Customer ID"
```

Look at each sale first. Then decide whether that customer has a sale that fits your 60-day condition. If your logic requires focusing on the initial sale then you'll have to do something different like this:

```
select "Customer ID",
    case when count(case when "Date" > firstDate then 1 end) > 0 then 'Retained' else 'Churned' end as Status
from (
    SELECT
        "Customer ID", "Date",
        min("Date") over (partition by "Customer ID") AS firstSale            
    FROM "Sales"
) t
where "Date" between firstSale and firstDate + interval '60 days'
group by "Customer ID"
```

It's not clear whether two sales on the initial date is a possibility or how you would treat that.

Comment: hi there, thanks for your answer. actually my logic involves counting the number of sales only done after the first sale. I have not been able to find a way to do it, I've tried nested queries but nothing so far. Do you have any idea how that might be achieved? Thanks!

Comment: thanks again! 
I tried the second one but it tells me that "Sale ID" needs to appear in the GROUP BY clause (which is weird because it's already aggregated as MIN).
I think it's because as someone said below the GROUP BY acts before the OVER.
just wondering, the WHERE clause will act overall the database, or row by row? I thought window functions were done exactly for this cases, but apparently it's not the case. Any workarounds? So far I've been unable to sort it out. Thanks!

Comment: That should have been the date rather than sale id. See if you have better luck with that. I agree the error doesn't make sense. That inner query ought to run all by itself so try that too.